# NoReverseMatch for Class-based delete view

Tags: django

I am having trouble trying to implement a class-based delete view as I have been having a NoReverseMatch error and I am unsure what is causing the problem.

Here is the error when I try to access my deleteview:
NoReverseMatch at /post/lesson_delete/3
Reverse for 'lesson_uploaded' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post\/(?P[0-9]+)\/lesson_uploaded\/$']

This is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='store-home'),
path('sub_home', SubListView.as_view(), name='store-sub_home'),
path('user/<str:username>/', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
path('about/', views.about, name='store-about'),
path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
path('post/<int:post_id>/lesson_upload/', UploadLessonView.as_view(), name='lesson_upload'),

path('post/<int:post_id>/lesson_uploaded/', LessonListView.as_view(), name='lesson_uploaded'),
path('post/lesson_delete/<int:pk>', LessonDeleteView.as_view(), name='lesson_delete'),
path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),

path('post/<int:pk>/change_sub/<slug:operation>/', views.change_sub, name='change_sub'),

path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),   
path('password-reset/',
 auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html'), name='password_reset'),   
path('password-reset/done/',
 auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),   
path('password-reset/confirmed/<uidb64>/<token>',
 auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),   
path('password-reset-complete/',
 auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),   
path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),

]
```

This is my views.py for my DeleteView:

```py
class LessonDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, 
DeleteView):
    model = Lesson
    success_url = '../'

    def test_func(self):
        lesson = self.get_object()
        # if self.post.request.user == lesson.post.author:
        return True
        # return False
```

These are my Models:

```py
class Lesson(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="lesson/pdf")
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, 
blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('lesson_upload', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.file.delete()
        self.title.delete()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default0.jpg', 
upload_to='course_image/')
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk' : self.pk})
```

This is my html template to render the delete view:

```html
{% extends "store/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div id="main">
        <table class="table mb-0">
        <thead>
          <tr>          
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Download</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for l in lesson %}
          <tr>
            <td>
                {% if l.file %}
                    {{ l.title }}
                {% else %}                  
                <h6>Not available</h6>
                {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>{{ l.post.author }}</td>
            <td>{% if l.file %}                 
                <a href="{{ l.file.url }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
target="_blank">Download</a>
            {% else %}
            <h6>Not available</h6>
            {% endif %}    
        </td>
        <td> <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'lesson_delete' l.id %}">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I am not able to display my deleteview and I am not sure what is the issue. My guess would be that in my html template, I am not writing correctly for my lesson.id.

Comment: If you get an error you need to post it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman sry just added!

Comment: I think its because of your url ordering. Can you post all the urls from urls.py?

Comment: @NalinDobhal i think you are right, my url link was from 'Lesson_uploaded' to 'Lesson_delete', because i wasnt sure how to have two pk in the url, so I prioritised on the one for my main model. But I just included those urls, hopefully you can help clarify.

Comment: try to move this url `'post/lesson_delete/<int:pk>'` before this one `'post/<int:pk>/update/'`.

Comment: @NalinDobhal hmm does not seem to work... still having the same error